# How can we read JSON file

Tags: json

Utility to read JSON file from file server
2. Utility should run at scheduled time let’s say 6AM
3. Error message if JSON file is not properly formatted
4. Error message if Category is missing and ITEM need that Category to be saved.
5. Entity mapping as per the given relationship in data model
5. Documentation for the API, preferably using any tool
6. Junit Test cases using Mockito
7. Use either MySQL or Oracle for API development
8. add one point as JSON validation for not null and value range

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not a place where you just give tasks and people do the work for you for free.

Comment: i tried below is it fine:

Comment: I tried this :-

Answer (score -1):

i tried below to cover first question of this problem but not sure what to do to answer remaining 7 questions related with this probelm:-
Create a class named "JSONRead" in eclipse. In this we will using "JSONParser" to convert the JSON string in the file to JSONOBject.
 In order to use JSON Parser makes sure that your string is in JSON format.

```
enter code here`enter code here`
enter code here
{
package logicProgramming;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JsonRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        //JsonParser to convert JSON string into Json Object

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("g:\\newfile.json"));
            //parsing the JSON string inside the file that we created earlier.

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            System.out.println(jsonObject);
            //Json string has been converted into JSONObject

            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
            System.out.println(name);

            String department = (String) jsonObject.get("department");
            System.out.println(department);

            String branch = (String) jsonObject.get("branch");
            System.out.println(branch);

            long year = (long) jsonObject.get("year");
            System.out.println(year);
            //Displaying values from JSON OBject by using Keys

            JSONArray remarks = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("remarks");
            //converting the JSONObject into JSONArray as remark was an array.
            Iterator<String> iterator = remarks.iterator();
            //Iterator is used to access the each element in the list 
            //loop will continue as long as there are elements in the array.
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
                //accessing each elemnt by using next function.
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

enter code here
enter code here
```

Thanks

Comment: is there any java or json expert who could verify what i have written is correct?

Comment: once it is done then folowing also needs to be done:-

Comment: 1. Utility to read JSON file from file server

2. Utility should run at scheduled time let’s say 6AM

3. Error message if JSON file is not properly formatted

4. Error message if Category is missing and ITEM need that Category to be saved.

5. Entity mapping as per the given relationship in data model

5. Documentation for the API, preferably using any tool

6. Junit Test cases using Mockito

7. Use either MySQL or Oracle for API development

8. add one point as JSON validation for not null and value range.

Comment: Validation Points:

 

Step 1: You have to read the file, If any Error, please correct.

Step 2: IF any category/item Missing, Null Message came or Any notification.

Step 3: Add the category and save the message,

Step 4: if Order not received it 6 AM, then Not file Uploaded Message must show OR repeat the previous order.

Step 5: Must add clock in Programmer.

Comment: Java or JSON experts please advise how can we complete it?

Comment: and if this is not the right forum then please also advise which is the correct forum where i can find out these answers ?

Comment: You need to put all information about your problem in the question itself. Don't put your attempt as an answer - it's clearly not an answer to your question, or you wouldn't be here.

Comment: yes it is not the answer but what can i do no one is helping me here on this forum what should i do now?

Comment: It would have been prudent to read the advice displayed around the form when you filled out your question - it makes clear what you should put, and not put, i.e. what constitutes a good question. Right now your question reads like you're setting someone a task, to do for free. As I've said, edit the question with what you've currently put as an answer. People will then see that you've edited the quesiton, and it'll bump up the list. People may then help. Later, with enough rep, you can also offer bounty.